# Error when attempting to run query activity via SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, query

I'm sending the following soap envelope to start a query activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com" xmlns:h="http://exacttarget.com">REMOVED</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Action>Start</Action>
     <Definitions>
        <Definition xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
           <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID>75c72f5a-e95e-4dc0-a58a-7879f08cdf6a</ObjectID>
        </Definition>
     </Definitions>
  </PerformRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Body>
  <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
  <RequestID>8156b410-54a4-4bff-b9f7-0419187a2b51</RequestID>
  </RetrieveResponseMsg>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there something wrong with my soap envelope or could this be something else? I've tried a few different combinations and nothing is working.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem.